# socket.io with Laravel not catching connection

Tags: laravel, socket.io

This is my client side code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });

      $("#send").click(function(){
        content = $("textarea").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{route('send.message')}}",
          method: "POST",
          data: {content},
          success: function(){
            socket.emit('message', content);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
      socket.on("channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
          console.log(message);
      });
  </script>
```

Node JS code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('channel', function(err, count) {});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("made socket connection", socket.id);
    });

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Laravel PHP Server side (ajax target):

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
      event(new EventName($request->all()));
      $message = new Message;
      $message->message = $request->content;
      $message->save();
    }
```

In client side, it returns the data being sent, you can see in the `socket.on(......)`, what I am trying to do is, once the message is sent through ajax, I want to emit that message using `socket.emit()`, and catch it in

```
io.on('connection', fuction(socket)({

});
```

But it cannot catch it there. Why is that? What I am trying to do is broadcast the message to other sockets except my socket. Like this to be exact

```
io.broadcast.emit()
```

Please how can I make it work? Thank you.

---

In response to @Laravelmeester
Hey sorry, I do have my event set up. But I did not post it in the code. I have this problem here:

When I have the socket.io listening inside the redis callback function like this:

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log(message); //look here
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', "huhu");
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', data)
        });
    });
});
```

When I `console.log(message)` it outputs 3-4x ? Why does it do that? I only have one client connected. So for example I send

> test123

, it would output

```
test123
test123
test123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lot of elements, or maybe you have these in place but not posted in your question.

I assume you made an event with artisan?

```
php artisan make:event SendSocketMessage
```

after that, it should look something like this, make sure that you add the $data var in the construct and pass it on to the correct channel in the broadcastOn().

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SendSocketMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;    

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;           
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the redis server running and your nodejs properly setup and keep the terminals open to see the results. 
You see that I used the laravel log function, because you can tail your laravel log and test the construct and broadcatOn functions, 
to see if your data comes through this event.

Now inside your controller where your firing the sendMessage function, on top you need to include the App\Event and eventname like this:

```
use Event;
use App\Events\SendSocketMessage;
```

Then you rewrite your function like this:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
      Event::fire(new SendSocketMessage($request->all()));
      $message = new Message;
      $message->message = $request->content;
      $message->save();
    }
```

Also console.log the message.data on the front end and see if that is logging or not.

Hope this helps. 
Best of luck!

--

Please share what you get on the console log, where you have the Message Recieved + Message Paremeter in here, your NodeJS:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('channel', function(err, count) {});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("made socket connection", socket.id);
    });

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Is that also outputting the 3-4x?

Comment: Hey @Laravelmeester , Thanks for replying. Please have a look at my question, I added something new :)

Comment: Are you able to be contacted? Maybe through personal message? @Laravelmeester

Comment: Yes, you can contact me through personal messages, no worries!

Comment: Oh silly me. I don’t have enough rep to create chat room. Do you mind inviting me? Thank you!